# Using Python open a list of CSV's and modify columns unix time to datetime - it errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a long list of CSV's I do NOT want to append into one, I wish to keep the CSV's names unchanged only change 2 columns from what currently has a 13 digit unix date to a  natural date time I.E YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.

I am  happy using Pandas that seems to be  the easier  way, but I am struggling with this, I had hoped something like this might have worked. Any help is appreciated!

Here is an example of unix time: 1640227953000 this converts to Thursday, 23 December 2021 02:52:33

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pathlib import Path # available in python 3.4 + 


dir = r'csv/' # raw string for windows.
csv_files = [f for f in Path(dir).glob('*.csv')] # finds all csvs in your folder.

print(csv_files)



for csv in csv_files: #iterate list
    df = pd.read_csv(csv) #read cs
    print(df.columns.tolist()) # used for trouble shooting
    df['values_authorTimestamp']=df['values_authorTimestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    df['values_committerTimestamp']=df['values_committerTimestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    #df['values_authorTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['values_authorTimestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # print(df)
    print(f'{csv.name} saved.')
    df.to_csv(f'csv/{csv.name}')

#values_committerTimestamp
```

This is working, saving to CSV's however it only gets through a number of them and throws an error, any ideas?

```
  File "Scripts/Audit/change-csv.py", line 16, in <module>
    df['values_authorTimestamp']=df['values_authorTimestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1082, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1137, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "Scripts/Audit/change-csv.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    df['values_authorTimestamp']=df['values_authorTimestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2021-11-04 17:19:24'
```

Comment: Can you add some example of datetimes in unix format?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Can you check edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are mixed formats of datetimes, try use `errors='coerce'` parameter for missing values if not mathed format and then replace missing values by another `Series` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values_authorTimestamp':[1640227953000,'2021-11-04 17:19:24']})

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_authorTimestamp'], unit='ms', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_authorTimestamp'], errors='coerce')

df['values_authorTimestamp'] = d1.fillna(d2).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
  values_authorTimestamp
0    2021/12/23 02:52:33
1    2021/11/04 17:19:24
```

So your solution is changed:

```
for csv in csv_files: #iterate list
    df = pd.read_csv(csv) #read cs
    d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_authorTimestamp'], unit='ms', errors='coerce')
    d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_authorTimestamp'], errors='coerce')

    df['values_authorTimestamp'] = d1.fillna(d2).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    d11 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_committerTimestamp'], unit='ms', errors='coerce')
    d21 = pd.to_datetime(df['values_committerTimestamp'], errors='coerce')

    df['values_committerTimestamp'] = d11.fillna(d21).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')


    # print(df)
    print(f'{csv.name} saved.')
    df.to_csv(f'csv/{csv.name}')
```